# How can I find missing Global Resource records?

Tags: asp.net, app-globalresources

I have 3 Global resource files:

```
WebResources.resx
WebResources.resx.es
WebResources.resx.it
```

When making changes to my application, I always add the default global resource records (English) to the `WebResources.resx` file. However, I don't always have the Spanish and Italian versions at the time, so these need to be added at a later stage.

My project manager has suggested that whenever adding a record into the `WebResources.resx` file, then a blank record should be added into the `.es` and `.it` versions. Then when it comes to finding out which records need a translation, we can order by the value and see a list of the blanks.

I like the fall-back of using Global Resources, that if there is not a record in the specified resource file, then the default record is returned. By adding a blank record this is preventing the fall back.

Is there a better way of finding out what records are missing from the `.es` and `.it` resource files?

Comment: What about [something like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16068/Zeta-Resource-Editor)

Comment: @musefan Thats exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tools around that should help you do what you need.

[Here is one you could try for example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16068/Zeta-Resource-Editor)